# How I can compute normals vectors for a tessellated terrain?

Tags: opengl, c++, procedural-generation, normals, tessellation

I would like compute normals vectors for a tessellated terrain generated procedurally, in order to use them for a basic lighting. I don't know how I could do it. I can do it in the Tessellation Evaluation Shader (TES)? or in the Geometry Shader? The Geometry Shader allows me to compute normals, but is it expensive, so I would like avoid him.

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What procedure do you use to generate the vertex positions or heights?

Comment: Basically I use an heightmap generated using the fratcal noise. The element of the heigthmap determines the height of each vertex.In the Application stage I send a flat terrain to the GPU that will be subdivideb by the tessellation shader.

Comment: I assume your TES is sampling the height-map for the displacement, right? Normals can easily be calculated by sampling multiple points close to your current position, crossing some vectors and averaging the results.